# After creating a new class Airport and make some changes in flights when i migrate it after makemigrations throws IntegrityError

Tags: django-models

from django.db import models

## Create your models here.

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city}, ({self.code})"
class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="departures" )
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="arrivals")
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.origin} To {self.destination}")
```

**ERROR**

- On running command **python manage.py migrate**, it shows IntegrityError.

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, flights, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying flights.0002_auto_20201119_1418...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\airline\manage.py", line 22, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\airline\manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py", line 395, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 229, in apply_migration
migration_recorded = True
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 35, in **exit**
self.connection.check_constraints()
File "C:\Users\arora\Documents\Harvard\lec-4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 343, in check_constraints
raise IntegrityError(
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'flights_flight' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: flights_flight.origin_id contains a value 'new york' that does not have a corresponding value in flights_airport.id.

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete the flight entry you made previously.
use flight.delete() in the shell

(you will need to also reset the code to the previous values of origin and destination as CharFields and not ForeignKeys, makemigration again to remove the airport class, migrate changes and go back in the shell, access the flight in the database and delete it ..the go back and make the changes with the airport class)